# Is it possible to update a group's auto-reply settings using the API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm using [Gmail.Users.Settings.updateVacation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateVacation) to update our customer service rep's vacation responses automatically over the weekend and after-hours, so our customers who e-mail when we're not in the office get an informative message of when they can expect a response.

I am attempting to do the same thing with our Google Groups, but have not been able to find the correct API call. If I use the same method as above, but with a group's e-mail address, I get a "Delegation denied" error (even though I'm an Owner of the group). I suspect this is because a Group is not a User, and is just different.

I've found the [Manage Group Settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/manage) API, which essentially has just one update method, and you use properties to specify what you want to update on the group. The problem is, there is no auto-reply property name that I can find.

How do I update a Group's auto-reply settings?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved through the API.

All the possible methods are present in the Groups Settings API so if you didn't find the expected method there, then it means that is not possible through the API.

What you can do instead is to file a **Feature Request** [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Groups Settings API - Groups Resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups#json).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the unambiguous answer!